# Switch On/Off flash while recording the Video in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I am recording video from my iPhone app.

I am using an overlay over the camera and placed a button in the overlay. I want to know with the help of which function can I turn camera's flash on/off while the video is being recorded.

How can I set a flash button in the camera overlay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using UIImagePickerController (from your tag), use the [cameraFlashMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) provided by UIImagePickerController to control the flash.

You can set its value to UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff, UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto or UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn. Default is auto.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `AVFoundation` for video recording, You should first check if device has torch/flash because torch is available when video is being recorded from the back camera, you can not have the torch/flash when using front camera.
using something like this

```
- (BOOL) hasTorch
{
    return [[[self avCaptureDeviceInput] device] hasTorch];
}
```

and then set the torch accordingly using `AVCaptureTorchMode`

```
- (void) setTorchMode:(AVCaptureTorchMode)torchMode
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];
    if ([device isTorchModeSupported:torchMode] && [device torchMode] != torchMode) {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
            [device setTorchMode:torchMode];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        } else {
            id deleg = [self delegate];
            if ([deleg respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {
                [deleg acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you follow the [AVCam Demo from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) you will get your answers basically.